# Getting launcher on dual monitors

Tags: 13.10, launcher, monitor

I recently bought a second monitor for my computer. Setting it up was fairly easy, but when I turned the monitor I found that the unity launcher bar that is on the right monitor did not transfer over to my newly bought left monitor. I would like to have a launcher on each monitor. I saw some places where people went to "Display' in settings and could get it from there but when I went into display the only things I could change were the resolution of my screens and if I wanted to mirror them. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to `14.04` ? I don't remember how it was in `13.10` but in `14.04` these is an option in the `Display settings` panel for that purpose, to select on which screen to show the launcher, or even whether to show it on both screens.

Comment: Upgrading to 14.04 should not be needed to get launchers on all monitors. It's working fine in 13.10.

Answer (score 1):

Running 13.10 here myself and if you go to settingsmenu Screen Dislay, there is an option called 'launcher placement'  which you can set to 'All displays', which should display the launcher on all screens.

The options are in order:
Resolution
Rotation
Launcher Placement
Sticky edges

If this is not the case for you, could you perhaps post a screenshot of your Screen Display window?

Hope that helps.